# in_array() works fine but throws error?

Tags: php

AFAIK - `in_array()` should return `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

In my case, It does validate as true - but still throwing an error:

> [function.in-array]: Wrong datatype for second argument

The line is this :

```
in_array($key,$instance['cfl2']);
```

and the `$instance['cfl2']` is a verified `array` which looks like this :

`array(2) { [0]=> string(8) "price" [1]=> string(6) "age" }`

My questions are :

- What am I doing wrong.
- Why it is throwing an error (but still working fine and returns true)
- Is the problem occur because I use some kind of nested array ? (meaning that an array item `$instance['cfl2']` is actually an array by itself ?

I also tried `$is = $instance['cfl2']` and `in_array($key,$is)` - but the result was the same error.

Comment: Try `in_array($key, (array) $instance['cfl2'])`

Comment: This is odd. What says `gettype($instance['cfl2'])`?

Comment: @BobSponge - hmmmm - seems to be working . no error ! thanks . add it as an answer and I will accept it . but may I also know WHY is it doing so, and if there is an error , why it still validates as true ??

Comment: Why length of "age" is 6? `string(6) "age"`

Comment: @BobSponge hmm - good question . also why price is (8) . maybe it is part of the problem ? the array might have non-english characters. itmight got something to do with another question that I posted today - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452324/php-mysql-results-with-order-limit-non-english-character-fail

Comment: @DanLee - `gettype($instance['cfl2'])` says "array"

Comment: @BobSponge - your first comment actually eliminated the warning message . but I would really like to know why in order to avoid this kind of problems in the future ..

Comment: @BobSponge - I do not mean to nag , but if you have time, you might want to add your proposed solution as an answer for me to accept (and mark this question as closed )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast a variable to an array to avoid this error:

`in_array($key, (array) $instance['cfl2'])`

Answer (score 0):

`in_array()` will deal as `in_array("search", $instance)`.

If you are using a nested or multidiamentional array, then `in_array()` wont work and you should write a separate function to handle this.  Or use `array_key_exists()` instead. It will work for certain specific situations. Find out if your requirement is met.

ie

```
if(array_key_exists($key,$instance['cfl2']))
```